# Parse.Com Error saving relation

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
         ParseRelation<ParseUser> relation = profile_user.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_LIKES);
        relation.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        profile_user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewProfilePic.this, "Liked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

In this program when a person visits a particular profile he can like that profile. 
profile_user is a ParseUser object which is a particular profile. If the user clicks on the like button the current user should be added to the profile_user 's "likes relation. But this does not happen . Please help!

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error? Any exception in the logcat?  maybe you can provide more code?  Are you sure you have registered your button with an onClickListener?

Comment: Yes. It confirmed by the toast "Liked" and I don't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. By default parse does not allow you to save unauthenticated users for security reasons I.e only the current user value can be modified. I overcame this using parse cloud code.